# Can anything in Area 51 become 'Community Wiki'?

Tags: discussion, area-51, community-wiki

If one is seeking a higher reputation, as many users are, the community-wiki tag can be the end-of-the-line for some of your reputation windfalls.  But I don't see a mention of 'community wiki' in the Area 51 Faq.

Is there a community wiki tag or the equivalent in Area 51?

Or are there any plans to do so in the near future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the questions asked on Area 51 are sample questions used to define proposed Stack Exchange sites. The questions asked are not answered on Area 51 but rather are rated as either being a good "on-topic" or "off-topic" question for the given proposal.

Because of the nature of Area 51 (being the launchpad for potential Q&A sites, not a Q&A site itself), it would never make sense to mark a question or a proposal as "community wiki".